# Using money_column gem with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

I'm a rails noob... using Rails 3.1

I'm trying to use the [money_column gem](https://github.com/tobi/money_column). I installed the gem, added to my gemfile, bundle install. I set up a Product model like the example.

My Product model is:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product_category
  attr_accessible :sku, :name, :description, :price, :available, :product_category_id
  money_column :price

end
```

I created some seed data in seeds.rb. When I run rake db:seed, though, I'm getting an error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `money_column' for #<Class:0x007fccbd26e468>
```

Have I missed something in installing money_column?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the Money gem. It handles money, currency and exchange *extremely* well. https://github.com/RubyMoney/money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the source code of that gem and I think it would work if you changed your model to this:

```
require 'money'
require 'money_column'

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MoneyColumn

  belongs_to :product_category
  attr_accessible :sku, :name, :description, :price, :available, :product_category_id
  money_column :price

end
```

Also, are you sure you are using the right gem?  The [official money_column gem on rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/money_column) is this one:
https://github.com/chargify/money_column

Comment: Ah, I see, having to add in 'require'. Makes sense. Is there some automatic way to know what needs to be required for a specific gem? And yes, you are right, I was looking at the wrong library on github.

Comment: Usually you just do `require gem_name` but that's not good enough for this gem.  There is some Bundler command (maybe `Bundler.require`) that will require all the gems in the Gemfile.